# Instalei o VirtualBox no meu Fedora 21 mas sempre que abro uma máquina o meu note trava totalmente

Tags: linux, virtualbox

Depois de muitos problemas consegui instalar o VirtualBox em sua última versão no Fedora21 também com sua última versão do kernel mas quando abro alguma máquina virtual o meu note trava totalmente e só desligando e ligando novamente pra voltar "à vida". O meu note é um Dell Latitude 7350, 64 bits, com 8GB de RAM, 500GB de HD, processador Intel Core M-5Y71 CPU @ 1.20GHz x 4. Ou seja, pelo tipo do note não era para dar esse problema. O que poderia ser?

Comment: [4 votos para fechar e nenhum comentário até então!](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2693/132)

Comment: Só para te informar, a sua pergunta está sendo fechada como fora-do-escopo por ser algo que não tem a ver com programação.

Comment: Desculpe pelo inconveniente @VictorStafusa eu estava vendo o site[http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184430/installing-virtualbox-in-fedora-21-using-rpm-fusion-is-giving-me-problems] e este é do StackOverFlow e aqui achei a tag linux então acabei me confundindo.

Comment: Não estou o culpando de nada, muito menos de ser inconveniente. O chato é pessoas fecharem a sua pergunta sem ninguém te avisar nada.

Comment: Sim, obrigada @VictorStafusa.